# Como representar as classes do MVC na UML?

Tags: mvc, uml

Como representar as classes do modelo mvc na UML? Um colega me falou que ele coloca apenas o Control na sua modelagem.

Esta correto? 
Outra duvida seria se eu preciso colocar a classe de conexão com o banco.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rosberg, fiz um representação bem grosseira de como poderia representar em UML, segue na imagem abaixo. Em relação a classe de conexão ao banco, o mais indicado seria você utilizar um padrão de projeto, nesse caso o DAO (Data Acess Object). [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma coisa que eu até esqueci de inserir no meu diagrama foi a relação entre as classes dentro dos pacotes. Em UML eu tenho estereótipos para representar classe de controle e de interface, fica bem mais visual, acho legal você utilizar. Se a classe de controle acessa o modelo não vejo a necessidade de estabelecer uma relação entre o modelo e a interface novamente, então faz o seguinte o view chama o controle e o controle chama o modelo, dessa maneira fica muito interessante seu diagrama. Na verdade o factory seria legal se você fosse estabelecer conexão entre mais de um tipo de banco de dados, como exemplo um postgres, mysql e oracle, assim eu faria uma fábrica de conexões. Já o DAO é ótimo para o acesso a dados então recomendo muito vc utilizar o Dao.

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito! Valeu!