# Dizer mais com menos no diagrama de classe UML

Tags: php, laravel-5, uml, documentação, diagrama

Eu estou com uma dúvida em como elaborar um diagrama para este cenário:

- Aplicação em Laravel MVC
- Muito código igual nas camadas view e controller queria omitir isso
- Trabalho da facul

Eu queria saber se é possível e aceito eu apenas criar as classes com os nomes e diferenciar apenas aquelas que tem alguma regra de negócio, algo parecido com essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168077/35153

Então ao invés de ter no diagramas as views como:

ListagemCliente

ListagemCarro

ListagemFuncionario

AtualizarCliente

AtualizarCarro

AtualizarFuncionario

...

Eu pensei de fazer assim:

Listagem

Atualizar

...

Como as views são parecidas eu queria saber se posso fazer algo genérico sem especificar os nomes nas views relacionados ao CRUD

No controller acho que só precisaria dizer(nota de rodapé) que os métodos de crud são bem parecidos por causa do ORM e só deixar o nome dos controllers sem os métodos, com excessão de regras de neǵocio.

Comment: Sua pergunta tá meio confusa, não dá pra saber se tem a ver com diagrama de classes ou OO.

Mas se o que você quer fazer é criar abstrações pra reaproveitar código nos CRUD's te aconselho esse [link](https://medium.com/by-vinicius-reis/repository-pattern-n%C3%A3o-precisa-ser-chato-principalmente-com-laravel-d97235b31c7e)

Comment: @AndréLuizdeGusmão obrigado pelo comentário, alterei a pergunta, acho que ficou mais claro.

Comment: pq você colocaria as views em um diagrama de classes? O ponto principal é o que devo comunicar com esse diagrama. Depois que responder isso fica simples de elaborar ele.

Comment: @rray Eu quero comunicar as classes e os métodos relacionados diretamente ao negócio, o CRUD está ligado, mas não é o foco neste caso